# Remove empty string elements from string array in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to get the contents of a text file, remove everything other than alphabets and then convert it into an array of `String`s for individual processing of words.
I do this for getting the text file :

```
String temp1= IOUtils.toString(FIS,"UTF-8");
String temp2=temp1.replaceAll("[,.!;:\\r\\n]"," ");
```

And then to tokenize the string, I do this:

```
String[] tempStringArray = temp2.split(" ");
```

The problem is that when the array is created, there are empty `String` at various indices.These empty `String` are at the position of linebreak, more than one whitespace, replaced punctuation marks, etc in the text file.
I want these empty `String`s to be removed from my `String` array or in a way which they are unable to enter the `String` array.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split by all whitespaces like: `String[] tempStringArray = temp2.split("\\s+")`

Comment: But this leaves us with and empty "" in the array!

Comment: @nayandhabarde, is this true? solution works well, at least for the above question. Maybe yours is a bit different. can you paste you string?

Comment: https://truecaller.blog/2018/01/22/life-as-an-android-engineer/ try requesting this page html as a response, at the end it has -->\n

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if you have more than one character from your character set [,.!;:\r\n] in a row, it will replace it with more than one empty space. When you call the `split()` method, it then places empty occurrences in the array that refer to the multiple blank spaces in a row.

You can use a regex in the `split()` method, which will work a lot better for your example.

Try repacing `temp2.split(" ")` with `temp2.split("\\s+")`. This will look for multiple spaces in a row, and just tokenise the text around the large gaps of empty space.

Answer (score 2):

While the answers of Daniel Arthur and Young Millie are correct, one can replace the two steps by directly splitting at the Characters you want to avoid:

```
String[] tempStringArray = temp1.split("[,.!;:\\s]+");
```

Comment: Works as well.Thanks for the answer